# CSS file kills my bootstrap theme in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I'm creating an Admin dash using a theme I found on wrap bootstrap: [Theme Link](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/nifty-responsive-admin-template-WB0048JF7)

I loaded the index.html, bootstrap.css, and all the associated images, fonts and js. After I run this it looks like it should sans css of course.

However, once I add the themes .css file it goes blank on me and only displays a nonfunctioning setting dropdown at the very bottom of the page.

I'd like to share pics but I'm new to stack overflow and don't have enough rep yet.

Facts on the build: 
Using Cloud9 IDE
Rails 4.0+Ruby2.1
Bootstrap 3.3.2

*When I load the index.html in Dreamweaver or open it in Chrome it works just fine*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard | Nifty - Responsive admin template.</title>


    <!--STYLESHEET-->
    <!--=================================================-->

    <!--Open Sans Font [ OPTIONAL ] -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&subset=latin" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--Bootstrap Stylesheet [ REQUIRED ]-->
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--Nifty Stylesheet [ REQUIRED ]-->
    <link href="nifty.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--Font Awesome [ OPTIONAL ]-->
    <link href="plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--Animate.css [ OPTIONAL ]-->
    <link href="plugins/animate-css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--Morris.js [ OPTIONAL ]-->
    <link href="plugins/morris-js/morris.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--Switchery [ OPTIONAL ]-->
    <link href="plugins/switchery/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--Bootstrap Select [ OPTIONAL ]-->
    <link href="plugins/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--Demo script [ DEMONSTRATION ]-->
    <link href="css/demo/nifty-demo.css" rel="stylesheet">




    <!--SCRIPT-->
    <!--=================================================-->

    <!--Page Load Progress Bar [ OPTIONAL ]-->
    <link href="plugins/pace/pace.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
```

**[EDIT]** I've also tried

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
```

and then adding the css inline on the index.html. For a second it looks as if it will take then it kicks out the same blank page with the settings dropdown.

Comment: did you try to load the bootstrap file at last ?

Comment: I just tried, no change.

Comment: Are those asset locations valid? Do you know what you are doing as far as not using Rails' asset pipeline?

Comment: Not using the asset pipeline?

As of now I have all the files referencing their locations in my pipeline: app/assets directory (images, js, css, plugins, fonts)

Comment: "The files in app/assets are never served directly in production." http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Load you `bootstrap.css` file below the .css file that is messing it up:

```
<link href="PATH/TO/BOOTSRAP" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="PATH/TO/STYLESHEET" rel="stylesheet"> `These styles will overwrite others`
```

Comment: I switched the order and its still the same problem.

Comment: @ds22 is your 'themes.css' below any other .css files? If so put it above them.